# Durable Functions to Unzip Blob storage file and copy the files to another blobStorage

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions

I have a Az function using implementation similar to this 
https://github.com/FBoucher/AzUnzipEverything/blob/master/Unzipthis.cs
I have BLOB trigger when a zip file is dropped. Az function Unzips it and copies the files to a new AZ blob location. **I get zip files with thousands of files inside it, so the copy process takes a very long time using foreach loop**. 
i tried using Parallel for each Async https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable that only works when running locally, when deployed it does not seems to work at all, no errors nothing, but nothing happens.

I want to try this Durable functions instead like in example below where each file copy is done by a another activity function. This will help speed up the process by having separate task for copy job, but problem is how do i pass the file to be copied to another blob location in Activity function?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/master/samples/precompiled/BackupSiteContent.cs

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that after triggering the condition, first copy the .zip file directly to the new blob, and then decompress it. Because I think the direct decompression and transfer speed will be very slow, similar to copying data from a computer in a USB flash drive.

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61831651/error-during-storage-blob-copy-operation-the-requested-operation-is-not-allowe/61862409#61862409) to copy the .zip file. You also can see my code in github. When copy finished, you can find the file and unzip it. You can see rGiosa's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49105491/how-to-unzip-large-size-zip-files-between-blob-containers-without-using-physical) . It will help you.